# Count of Occurring together in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have data set in which has Projects and products configured under it. I wanted to  find out count of projects that these products occurring together.

My data set:

[image]

I am looking for distinct output of

[image]

I tried to use self join but I am getting a duplicates in combinations like 
C2 C3 C4 and C2 C4 C3.

Can anyone suggest how can we achieve this?

Comment: You want count of Number of Projects that a product involved?  something like this
C3 product has 3projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a self join . . . twice:

```
select d1.product, d2.product, d3.product, count(*)
from dataset d1 join
     dataset d2
     on d1.project = d2.project and
        d1.product < d2.product join
     dataset d3
     on d2.project = d3.project and
        d2.product < d3.product
group by d1.product, d2.product, d3.product;
```